# C Makefile to compile some selective files

Tags: c, makefile

I am working on a C project which contains around 200 .c files and some .h files. Not all of these 200 files are required in the final product. Currently around 180 files needs to be compiled. We have a file "compile_only_these.c" which includes these 180 *.c files required for the project. Our makefile compiles only this file instead of individual .c files.

```
/* file: compile_only_these.c*/

#include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"
.
.
.
#include "file180.c"
```

But I think including .c files is a bad idea. Because every time I modify any of these files, all files are compiled again.

Can you suggest a better way to compile these files.

More info:

- All .c files are in same folder "../project/src"
- I keep adding new .c files which are required to be compiled. I dont want to modify Makefile every-time I add a new file.
- I still want to keep those 20 .c files which I am not compiling right now. I may use it in future. Deleting these files are moving them to other directory is not a solution

Comment: your approach is odd and not one I've ever seen in production code

Comment: @Vorsprung : I agree. Thats why I am planning to change this approach. btw this was not designed by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a variable in the makefile, a list of required object files, like this:

```
OBJS := file1.o file2.o ... file180.o
```

You can have Make construct it from the `compile_only_these.c` file like this:

```
OBJS := $(shell sed -e '/\#include/!d' -e 's/\#include "\(.*\)\.c"/\1.o/' compile_only_these.c)
```

Do you also need a hand with the rule that uses these objects to construct the final product?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, it's sort of a weird way to manage a project, but given what you have to work with, you might try something along this approach...

```
CC = gcc
OBJFILE = myprog

# Tweak to match whatever you compile with normally
CFLAGS  = -O2 -Wall -std=c89 -pedantic
LDFLAGS= # Extra flags here, for example -lm -pthread 

RM = rm -f

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

$(OBJFILE):$(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)


clean:
    $(RM) core *~ $(OBJS) $(OBJFILE)
```

You will obviously need to adjust the path(s) for the specifics of your build hierarchy if you want to do more in your make than just compile this list of files, but this is a general approach for grabbing all files with wildcard substitution.

Comment: My question is not about how to compile multiple files. I want to compile selective .c files. can u explain how does ur solution helps to compile only the required files instead of all files.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question initially.  If the only purpose of the "extra" files is to keep them around in case they are needed later, and you do not want to move them to a new folder to reflect that, you could either a) Keep a laundry list in the SRCS variable shown above, and maintain that as you add/remove file names.  b) rename the "extra" .c files to something like filename.c.saved (or pick a naming convention) that keeps them from being picked up by make.  The b) option would make adding/removing a file from the build no more complicated than a rename.